# How can I get a Kafka Streams app with exactly_once_v2 guarantee to work with AWS MSK

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, aws-msk

I'm having issues getting a Spring Boot Kafka Streams app to run when I have it configured with `processing.guarantee=exactly_once_v2` enabled. When I start my app up, it ultimately crashes (All my stream threads shut down) and i get the following exception logged:

`[Producer clientId=my-application-c170d5b4-ffe4-4734-a3e4-41b068b21060-StreamThread-2-producer, transactionalId=my-application-c170d5b4-ffe4-4734-a3e4-41b068b21060-2] Transiting to fatal error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TransactionalIdAuthorizationException: Transactional Id authorization failed.`

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Error encountered trying to initialize transactions [stream-thread [main]]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsProducer.initTransaction(StreamsProducer.java:169)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.initialize(RecordCollectorImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeIfNeeded(StreamTask.java:229)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.tryToCompleteRestoration(TaskManager.java:436)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.initializeAndRestorePhase(StreamThread.java:849)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:731)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:583)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:555)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TransactionalIdAuthorizationException: Transactional Id authorization failed.
```

My configuration is as follows:

```
        spring:
          kafka:
            producer:
              bootstrap-servers: <urls>
            properties:
              security.protocol: SASL_SSL
              sasl.mechanism: AWS_MSK_IAM
              sasl.jaas.config: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
              sasl.client.callback.handler.class: software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
            streams:
              application-id: my-application
              bootstrap-servers: <urls>
              replicationFactor: 3
              properties:
                acks: all
                retries: 3
                processing:
                  guarantee: exactly_once_v2
                num:
                  stream:
                    threads: 3
```

When I remove the exactly_once_v2 guarantee, it is able to work correctly.

In AWS im using the following policy statement:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "kafka-cluster:Connect",
        "kafka-cluster:AlterCluster",
        "kafka-cluster:DescribeCluster",
        "kafka-cluster:DescribeClusterDynamicConfiguration",
        "kafka-cluster:ReadData",
        "kafka-cluster:WriteData",
        "kafka-cluster:*Topic*",
        "kafka-cluster:WriteDataIdempotently
        "kafka-cluster:DescribeTransactionalId",
        "kafka-cluster:AlterTransactionalId",
        "kafka-cluster:AlterGroup",
        "kafka-cluster:DescribeGroup"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:kafka:<arn>:cluster/my-cluster/*",
        "arn:aws:kafka:<arn>:topic/my-cluster/*",
        "arn:aws:kafka:<arn>:transactional-id/my-cluster/*",
        "arn:aws:kafka:<arn>:group/my-cluster/*",
    ]
}
```

and I've also tried:

```
{
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "kafka-cluster:*"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:kafka:<arn>:*/my-cluster/*"
           ]
}
```

and that didn't work either. Based on the [RBAC role bindings defined in the confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/security.html#rbac-role-bindings), I thought I had the correct permissions set in my cluster, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Does anyone have any insights on potential IAM policy statements or other configurations I may be missing to get EOS working for my kafka streams app?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to successfully enable idempotence with the following two policies on a role:

1. AmazonMSKReadOnlyAccess AWS managed policy
2. Custom policy with the following:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "kafka-cluster:Connect",
        "kafka-cluster:DescribeTopic",
        "kafka-cluster:WriteData",
        "kafka-cluster:WriteDataIdempotently",
        "kafka-cluster:DescribeTransactionalId",
        "kafka-cluster:AlterTransactionalId",
        "kafka-cluster:DescribeGroup",
        "kafka-cluster:AlterGroup",
        "kafka-cluster:ReadData"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:kafka:<region>:<account>:cluster/<cluster_name>/<cluster_uuid>",
        "arn:aws:kafka:<region>:<account>:topic/<cluster_name>/<cluster_uuid>/<topic_name>",
        "arn:aws:kafka:<region>:<account>:group/<cluster_name>/<cluster_uuid>/*",
        "arn:aws:kafka:<region>:<account>:transactional-id/<cluster_name>/<cluster_uuid>/*"
    ]
```

Aside from the `kafka` permissions granted by the managed policy I don't see a delta between this and your policy statement.

Similar to what you tried, you could try opening up the permissions even further:

```
{
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "kafka*",
               "kafka-cluster:*"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "*"
           ]
}
```